# Need to speed up query, unable to gather output

Tags: sql, performance, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good morning. I've managed to write a 3000 line monstrosity of a query that seems capable of getting me the data I want, but can't seem to complete any task that would allow me to save the data. Running the query has completed one time in 30 seconds, one time in 180 seconds, but almost always takes about 800 seconds. When I attempted to export the data yesterday it ran for 20 hours (per the task progress panel) and I had to quit not knowing when it might finish.

The goal was to write a query that could output propensity scores for students, for the purpose of mitigating for a few characteristics in assessing the efficacy of interventions implemented by instructors to change their course over the summer.

The code is made up of a series of blocks of code that are repetitive.

I began the code using "WITH" in order to define some variables to use in the query.

First section/"[name] AS" calculates GPA for all students in the courses being examined at the time they were in the courses. Does not seem to run slow. This data is then gathered from that section to a section I named t_initialdata I used as a table to gather together various pieces into one space so I could avoid using joins throughout the rest of the code. I gathered the GPAs as well as their status in "student population" and "college" that semester. So at this point I've created a table with the GPA, student population, and college membership for all students in 2 semesters for a specific set of classes.

This is where the code gets dense with repetition. I'll post examples from each type of section.

There were 3 sections, one for each type of covariate: GPA, student population, and college. They all have pieces (GPA: above or below 2.75, Student Population: 12 different options, College: 26 different options) like this:

```
 v_gpaprob275Opre
  AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t_initialdata.person_uid) AS v_gpaprob275Opre
  FROM t_initialdata
  WHERE (t_initialdata.semester = '201610' AND t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75')),
 v_gpaprob275Opost
  AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t_initialdata.person_uid) AS v_gpaprob275Opost
  FROM t_initialdata
  WHERE (t_initialdata.semester = '201640' AND t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75')),
 v_gpaprobU275pre
  AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t_initialdata.person_uid) AS v_gpaprobU275pre
  FROM t_initialdata
  WHERE (t_initialdata.semester = '201610' AND t_initialdata.gpa < '2.75')),
 v_gpaprobU275post
  AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t_initialdata.person_uid) AS v_gpaprobU275post
  FROM t_initialdata
  WHERE (t_initialdata.semester = '201640' AND t_initialdata.gpa < '2.75')),
 v_gpaprobcalc275O
  AS (SELECT NVL(NULLIF(TRUNC(((v_gpaprob275Opre+v_gpaprob275Opost)/(v_gpaprob275Opre+v_gpaprobU275pre+v_gpaprob275Opost+v_gpaprobU275post)),3),0),.001) AS v_gpaproboutcome275O FROM v_gpaprob275Opre, v_gpaprobU275pre, v_gpaprob275Opost, v_gpaprobU275post),
 v_gpaprobcalcU275
  AS (SELECT NVL(NULLIF(TRUNC(((v_gpaprobU275pre+v_gpaprobU275post)/(v_gpaprob275Opre+v_gpaprobU275pre+v_gpaprob275Opost+v_gpaprobU275post)),3),0),.001) AS v_gpaproboutcomeU275 FROM v_gpaprob275Opre, v_gpaprobU275pre, v_gpaprob275Opost, v_gpaprobU275post),
```

The above gathers counts for above AND below 2.75 GPA for both before AND after intervention implementation, and then calculates a basic probability for a student being above or below 2.75 within this group. The same is done for all 12 student populations and all 26 colleges. You can also see my used of NVL/NULLIF to avoid 0 because I later use natural logs, which give errors if you have odds/probability of "0."

The above takes about 400 lines of code.

Next I have 24 blocks of code that look like:

```
v_scoreO000 AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcome00 AS v_scoreO000 FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalc00),
v_scoreO0AL AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeAL AS v_scoreO0AL FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcAL),
v_scoreO0AR AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeAR AS v_scoreO0AR FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcAR),
v_scoreO0AS AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeAS AS v_scoreO0AS FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcAS),
v_scoreO0BU AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeBU AS v_scoreO0BU FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcBU),
v_scoreO0CA AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeCA AS v_scoreO0CA FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcCA),
v_scoreO0CE AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeCE AS v_scoreO0CE FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcCE),
v_scoreO0CT AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeCT AS v_scoreO0CT FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcCT),
v_scoreO0ED AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeED AS v_scoreO0ED FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcED),
v_scoreO0EH AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeEH AS v_scoreO0EH FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcEH),
v_scoreO0EN AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeEN AS v_scoreO0EN FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcEN),
v_scoreO0GW AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeGW AS v_scoreO0GW FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcGW),
v_scoreO0HE AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeHE AS v_scoreO0HE FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcHE),
v_scoreO0HH AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeHH AS v_scoreO0HH FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcHH),
v_scoreO0HS AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeHS AS v_scoreO0HS FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcHS),
v_scoreO0LS AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeLS AS v_scoreO0LS FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcLS),
v_scoreO0LW AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeLW AS v_scoreO0LW FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcLW),
v_scoreO0MD AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeMD AS v_scoreO0MD FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcMD),
v_scoreO0NC AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeNC AS v_scoreO0NC FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcNC),
v_scoreO0NU AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeNU AS v_scoreO0NU FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcNU),
v_scoreO0PH AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomePH AS v_scoreO0PH FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcPH),
v_scoreO0SJ AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeSJ AS v_scoreO0SJ FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcSJ),
v_scoreO0SM AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeSM AS v_scoreO0SM FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcSM),
v_scoreO0UC AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeUC AS v_scoreO0UC FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcUC),
v_scoreO0VP AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeVP AS v_scoreO0VP FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcVP),
v_scoreO0YC AS (SELECT v_gpaproboutcome275O*v_stupopproboutcome0*v_collegeproboutcomeYC AS v_scoreO0YC FROM v_gpaprobcalc275O, v_stupopprobcalc0, v_collegeprobcalcYC),
```

Followed by 24 blocks of code that look like:

```
v_lnoddsO000 AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO000/(1-v_scoreO000)),4) AS v_lnoddsO000 FROM v_scoreO000),
v_lnoddsO0AL AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0AL/(1-v_scoreO0AL)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0AL FROM v_scoreO0AL),
v_lnoddsO0AR AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0AR/(1-v_scoreO0AR)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0AR FROM v_scoreO0AR),
v_lnoddsO0AS AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0AS/(1-v_scoreO0AS)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0AS FROM v_scoreO0AS),
v_lnoddsO0BU AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0BU/(1-v_scoreO0BU)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0BU FROM v_scoreO0BU),
v_lnoddsO0CA AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0CA/(1-v_scoreO0CA)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0CA FROM v_scoreO0CA),
v_lnoddsO0CE AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0CE/(1-v_scoreO0CE)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0CE FROM v_scoreO0CE),
v_lnoddsO0CT AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0CT/(1-v_scoreO0CT)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0CT FROM v_scoreO0CT),
v_lnoddsO0ED AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0ED/(1-v_scoreO0ED)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0ED FROM v_scoreO0ED),
v_lnoddsO0EH AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0EH/(1-v_scoreO0EH)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0EH FROM v_scoreO0EH),
v_lnoddsO0EN AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0EN/(1-v_scoreO0EN)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0EN FROM v_scoreO0EN),
v_lnoddsO0GW AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0GW/(1-v_scoreO0GW)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0GW FROM v_scoreO0GW),
v_lnoddsO0HE AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0HE/(1-v_scoreO0HE)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0HE FROM v_scoreO0HE),
v_lnoddsO0HH AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0HH/(1-v_scoreO0HH)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0HH FROM v_scoreO0HH),
v_lnoddsO0HS AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0HS/(1-v_scoreO0HS)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0HS FROM v_scoreO0HS),
v_lnoddsO0LS AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0LS/(1-v_scoreO0LS)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0LS FROM v_scoreO0LS),
v_lnoddsO0LW AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0LW/(1-v_scoreO0LW)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0LW FROM v_scoreO0LW),
v_lnoddsO0MD AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0MD/(1-v_scoreO0MD)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0MD FROM v_scoreO0MD),
v_lnoddsO0NC AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0NC/(1-v_scoreO0NC)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0NC FROM v_scoreO0NC),
v_lnoddsO0NU AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0NU/(1-v_scoreO0NU)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0NU FROM v_scoreO0NU),
v_lnoddsO0PH AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0PH/(1-v_scoreO0PH)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0PH FROM v_scoreO0PH),
v_lnoddsO0SJ AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0SJ/(1-v_scoreO0SJ)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0SJ FROM v_scoreO0SJ),
v_lnoddsO0SM AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0SM/(1-v_scoreO0SM)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0SM FROM v_scoreO0SM),
v_lnoddsO0UC AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0UC/(1-v_scoreO0UC)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0UC FROM v_scoreO0UC),
v_lnoddsO0VP AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0VP/(1-v_scoreO0VP)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0VP FROM v_scoreO0VP),
v_lnoddsO0YC AS (SELECT TRUNC(ln(v_scoreO0YC/(1-v_scoreO0YC)),4) AS v_lnoddsO0YC FROM v_scoreO0YC),
```

The above blocks calculate first a probability for any set of three circumstances: a GPA above/below 2.75, student population membership, and student college membership. Then the second block converts the probability into odds and then the odds into natural logs - which are our propensity scores.

Here's where it SEEMS to get slow, but I included all of the above because maybe that's what is really slowing things down? I don't know enough to know what exactly is kicking me here. The following is the code used to select it all into the grid so that I can save it:

```
SELECT t_initialdata.person_uid,
             CASE WHEN t_initialdata.semester = '201610' then '0'
             ELSE '1'
             END AS "Pre(0)-Post(1)",
             CASE
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = '00' THEN v_lnoddsO000
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'AL' THEN v_lnoddsO0AL
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'AR' THEN v_lnoddsO0AR
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'AS' THEN v_lnoddsO0AS
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'BU' THEN v_lnoddsO0BU
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'CA' THEN v_lnoddsO0CA
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'CE' THEN v_lnoddsO0CE
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'CT' THEN v_lnoddsO0CT
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'ED' THEN v_lnoddsO0ED
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'EH' THEN v_lnoddsO0EH
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'EN' THEN v_lnoddsO0EN
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'GW' THEN v_lnoddsO0GW
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'HE' THEN v_lnoddsO0HE
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'HH' THEN v_lnoddsO0HH
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'HS' THEN v_lnoddsO0HS
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'LS' THEN v_lnoddsO0LS
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'LW' THEN v_lnoddsO0LW
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'MD' THEN v_lnoddsO0MD
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'NC' THEN v_lnoddsO0NC
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'NU' THEN v_lnoddsO0NU
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'PH' THEN v_lnoddsO0PH
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'SJ' THEN v_lnoddsO0SJ
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'SM' THEN v_lnoddsO0SM
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'UC' THEN v_lnoddsO0UC
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'VP' THEN v_lnoddsO0VP
             WHEN t_initialdata.gpa >= '2.75' AND t_initialdata.student_population = '0' AND t_initialdata.college = 'YC' THEN v_lnoddsO0YC
```

The above, from "CASE" onward has 24 blocks much like the sections above. I feel like this is where I am getting the slowdown.

I've been working on this for well over a month. I believed I could solve it myself, and through the use of other peoples' errors and problems - but I've come down to where I don't think I have the time to figure this out myself. I thought I had it solved, but now it just won't let me save the data I'm querying.

I'm able to make this query and get it to display on the grid. It takes about 10 minutes.
I'm able to hit CTRL+END and get it to display all of the rows of the table pretty rapidly.
But as soon as I try to save it to an excel file... it fails. I've tried to do it through generating a report and then saving it from there. I tried saving it once I'd hit CTRL+END. I tried saving it and letting it re-run the query. In all cases - the query is just running and running.

I need help. :(

Comment: I don't think the last `CASE` clause is making the query slow (I can be wrong). The issue I see is that you are creating 24 CTEs using `CROSS JOIN`. Then, you are forcing the engine to materialize them when you use them further to compute another 24 CTEs. Only after that your `CASE` clause is computed. Usually CTEs act as a barrier for optimization; they also don't have indexes per se, but need to rely on indexes of their result sets, if available.

Comment: Maybe if you could provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result, we can help you rewrite the statement in a more efficient way. Not with 24 cases, but 2 or 3 will suffice to illustrate the rules that govern the data.

Comment: " I'm able to hit CTRL+END and get it to display all of the rows of the table pretty rapidly. But as soon as I try to save it to an excel file... it fails." Fails how? Cause once you've exhausted the fetching, all rows brought back, an export won't go back to the database to run the query again. How many rows are we talking about? You could just export it as you run it, spool file.csv select /*csv*/ ... from tables; - execute with f5

Comment: The first comment - I'm not sure what to do with. Would that necessarily take it from "slow" to query through to "damn near impossible" to export? 

How should I provide what you asked for in the second comment? I don't see how I can add a screenshot with the result I'm getting? And adding code for the CTE "table" I made to call all this "t_initialdata" is too long to paste here. Should I further add to/edit the initial post? @TheImpaler

Comment: @thatjeffsmith It doesn't "fail" I guess... but so far I've tried waiting up to an hour for the export to happen after doing the CTRL+END. It just keeps a display up there that says "running." How does export as I run it work? If the last line of your post is a mini-step-by-step it flew over my newbie head. :(

Comment: @thatjeffsmith It was actually (I just noticed) your own post/article that guided me to trying CTRL+END. I was very hopeful. Is there an option I need to change to make it save the export from the grid instead of re-running the query?

Comment: how many rows did you query? if it's MILLIONS, one doesnt just build an excel file w/o a LOT of work. export it to CSV instead, it'll be much faster, then you can open that in excel and convert if it you want

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Overall it is querying 10,916 rows. It just now took me 840 seconds to query the whole thing, and then once I hit CTRL+END it took about 40 seconds to get me from the initial 50 to 10,916.

Comment: something is going wrong, building an 11,000 rows xls file should be pretty much INSTANT...unless you're telling me you have like a 1,000 columns in your query too. What version of sqldev are you using?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I think there are a lot of different columns in the CTEs? But in the output from the query, the part I'm trying to export, there are 3 columns. Person_UID, Pre-Post status, and Propensity Score. I am running Version 19.4.0.354 Build 354.1759.

Comment: does the log panel show any errors? i would probably just ctrl+A, ctrl+c, alt-tab to excel, ctrl+v at this point

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Is there a way to show any errors while it is running? I can't get to the "end" of an export to see any errors that may pop up at the end. If I had a way to send you the code I could send the whole thing for you to skim briefly, that'd be up to you. Ultimately - I had no idea I could just CTRL+A/C/V this. That just saved me. It didn't fix the problem, but it got me where I need to be at the moment. 

I'd still like to fix this - the University wants this turned into a workable solution for mitigating confounding covariates when evaluating interventions in the future.

Comment: turn your query into an application - APEX would be nice

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Is that recommendation on the basis of the idea that something like this could be done such that it runs faster in an app? I am Googling Apex right now to see what it is as a language. Working with SQL last summer and this summer is the first time I've learned a coding language in 17 years (since PERL as a teen). I am hopeful I can find a way to remain on this project past my summer term.